# RequiredFieldValidator in code behind with ValidationSummary

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, validation

I am dynamically creating a list of questions (Labels and TextBoxes in a table).
Some questions need to be filled in, so I'm also creating the RequiredFieldValidators in the code behind.

To display the ErrorMessages, I use a ValidationSummary.
What I want to do is to display a '*' next to the TextBox and the question in the ValidationSummary.

On the aspx page it could be done like this:

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="reqFieldValWOline" runat="server" CssClass="errorLabelNoBox"
                                        ControlToValidate="txtWOline" ErrorMessage="the question">*
            </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

(the '*' in between the tags)
The summary will display the ErrorMessage.

How can I accomplish this in the code behind?

Comment: I've looked through the properties, but I don't think there is one I could use to do what I want. I'm just wondering if anyone knows how to do this or if it's even possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the Text property of validator e.g.

```
reqFieldValWOline.Text = "*"
```

Comment: Oh of course! Totally overlooked that property. You have my thanks.